# jquery date picker extension library

Tags: datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

This code snippet runs fine here as just a snippet, but when we add it to the cart the date picker and calender is are both not visible and inspecting in chrome we see:

Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function
at theme.js?v=5845886865919317655:5165

```js
const days = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"];

const unavailable = {
  dates: ["2020/12/1", "2020/11/25", "2020/11/26", "2020/11/27", "2020/12/11", "2020/12/12", "2020/12/24", "2020/12/25", "2020/12/26", "2020/12/27", "2020/12/31", "2021/1/1"],
  days: ["Saturday", "Monday", "Friday", "Sunday"],
};

$("#dateDiv").datepicker({
  inline: true,
  altField: '#dateInput',
  minDate: '+2',
  maxDate: '+18',
  beforeShowDay: function(date) {
    const ymd = date.getFullYear() + "/" + ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + "/" + ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2);
    const day = date.getDay();
    if ($.inArray(ymd, unavailable.dates) < 0 && $.inArray(days[day], unavailable.days) < 0) {
      return [true, "enabled", "Book Now"];
    } else {
      return [false, "disabled", "Booked Out"];
    }
  },
  onSelect: function(dateText) {
    $('#dateInput').val(dateText);
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<div>
  <label for="date">Pick a delivery date:</label>
  <input hidden id="dateInput" type="text" name="attributes[date]" required autofocus/>
  <div id="dateDiv"></div>
  <span class="instructions">We currently ship corals Monday...</span>
</div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: Also note that the date 12/1/2020 appears to be a valid option, but we put it in the unavailable dates section...

Comment: https://9zg4h0idcu1b73k1-28956655715.shopifypreview.com